# ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime() from NServiceBus.Host

Tags: service, timeout, nservicebus, startup

We have an NServiceBus Windows service that takes a while to register modules when starting up.  We would like to request additional time from the Service Manager to start up properly.  For services not using NServiceBus, this would be done using `ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime`.  How would this be done using NServiceBus.Host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, we have opened up an issue to support this in future versions

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/1046

On workaround would be to increase the timeout for you service using the registry:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344

Comment: Thanks.  We removed NServiceBus.Host and used Topshelf instead.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up removing NServiceBus.Host and using Topshelf instead.  Note additional config required on service startup.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HostFactory.Run(hf =>
    {
        hf.Service<MailboxListenerService>(svc =>
        {
            svc.ConstructUsing(mls => new MailboxListenerService());
            svc.WhenStarted((mls, control) => mls.Start(control));
            svc.WhenStopped(mls => mls.Stop());
        });
    });
}

public class MailboxListenerService
{
    private RunWebApi _webApiRunner;

    public MailboxListenerService()
    {
    }

    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        hostControl.RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MailboxListenerModule());

        Configure.With()
            .DefineEndpointName("my.endpoint.name")
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => typeof(Messaging.Markers.IEvent).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .Log4Net<NlogAppenderForLog4Net>(a => { })
            .NinjectBuilder(kernel)
            .MsmqTransport()
                .MsmqSubscriptionStorage("my.subscription.storage")
            .DisableTimeoutManager()
            .DisableSecondLevelRetries()
            .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false);

        _webApiRunner = kernel.Get<RunWebApi>();
        _webApiRunner.Run();

        return true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _webApiRunner.Stop();
    }
}
```